# Angular JS Not Sending Data To Web Api

Tags: angularjs, web, asp.net-web-api

[image]

[image]

[image]

Angular Post method not sending data to web api Controller. $http call to web api but its null.

Comment: use ng-model insted of data-ng-model at all, let me know

Comment: Yes i think Rakeschand is right, you need to initialize, let me to upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest() {
  if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS"){
    Response.Flush();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Define(Initialize) `$FirstName`, `LastName`, `Email`, `Number` as null first.

```
$scope.FirstName = null;
$scope.LastName = null;
$scope.Email = null;
$scope.Number = null;
```

or You could just use `$scope.user` as

```
$scope.user = {
    id : 0,
    FirstName : null,
    LastName : null,
    Email : null,
    Password : null
};
```

And pass in ng-model as `user.FirstName`

**EDIT:**

Build `$scope.user` outside the `CreateUser` Function

```
$scope.CreatUser=function(){
   $http{(...)};
}
```

**ENDS**

Comment: $scope.FirstName = null;
    $scope.LastName = null;
    $scope.Email = null;
    $scope.Number = null;

    $scope.User = {
        Id:'0',
        FirstName: '',
        LastName: '',
        EMail: '',
        Password: '',
        Mobile:'0'
    };

Comment: $scope.CreateUser = function () {
        debugger;
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:50048/api/SingUp/Post',
            data: $scope.User,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.productsData.push(response.data);
            $scope.clear();
            alert("Successfully !!!");
        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
    };

Comment: I've change my code but still its pass null , i've also remove data and now i just use ng-model.

Comment: Build `$scope.user` outside CreateUser function, it's re initiating inside the CreateUser method

Answer (score 1):

Move $scope.User to the controller scope :

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
   $scope.User = {
    id : 0,
    FirstName : null,
    LastName : null,
    Email : null,
    Password : null
    };

    $scope.CreatUser=function(){
      $http{(...)};
    }

})
```

And pass in ng-model as User.FirstName.

Comment: depanding on this that you have send to me ,https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gjyS.png , youre not doing it right . you need to delete the $scope.user that inside the CreatUser function

Comment: if m not sending model and m sending sting value but still its sending null. can you please check header and content-type value is ok?

Comment: i will edit my answer above with the full code , give me a sec

Comment: public httpResponsMessage Post([FromBody] SignUpView DataFromUI){

Comment: i've also try with Post([FromBody] SignUpView DataFromUI) but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

you are facing this issue because your header request `content-type` is : `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which will not work correctly. Try change it to `application/json`