# MVC controller method not receiving json data from $http post

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This might be basic question but I couldn't find where the issue is. I am using .Net Core for by back end and **angularJS** for front end. below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
<input type="text" ng-model="email"><br />
<input type="text" ng-model="password"><br />
<input type="submit" ng-click="login()">
</div>
```

**AngularJS Code**

```
app.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http', function (scope, http) {

scope.login = function () {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/loginInfo',
        data: { email: scope.email, password: scope.password },
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
    http(req)

        .then(function successCallback(response) {

        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
};
}]);
```

**Back end c#**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult loginInfo(string email, string password)
{
  //do something here
}
```

When I debug this I can see that payload is having the email and password values but anyhow they are not getting passed to the controller method. I can see that controller method is being hit but the values show as null.

things I have tried:

- Setting the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
- Passing the data as Json object
- Converting scope values to string

None of them seem to be working. anyone faced this kind of issue or expert opinion please.

Followed this post [Angular JS Not Sending Data To Web Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282466/angular-js-not-sending-data-to-web-api) . didn't quite get the approved answer or it is not related to my issue.

Comment: You have to use the `[FromBody]` attribute on your parameters e.g. `loginInfo([FromBody]string email, [FromBody]string password)`

Comment: tried that also. the value still says null.

Comment: Have you tried it with a model parameter?  e.g. `loginInfo([FromBody]Credentials creds)`

Comment: @Brad That worked!!! so any request from angular $http should be picked up as [FromBody] on the server side? can you please explain, that would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core MVC the default content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (for handling HTML form data).  The `[FromBody]` attribute tells the model binder to instead try and create the model from JSON content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the `[FromBody]` attribute with a model parameter.

```
public class Credentials
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Login([FromBody]Credentials creds)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This is because in ASP.NET Core MVC the default content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (for handling HTML form data). The `[FromBody]` attribute tells the model binder to instead try and create the model from JSON content.

Comment: yep, got it. Thanks @Brad. then how can i send requests with just one parameter like just a string or int where i don't need to create models.

Answer (score 1):

You must create an Class or Interface to send several parameters

```
public class PostParams
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}     
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult loginInfo(PostParams params)
{
  //do something here

}
```

Comment: tried that, doesn't work. the model values still show as null.

Comment: please just take a look in the web tools if you  are sending a **OPTION** request or  a **POST** request, in angular normally the controller is calling twice take a look if you have this behavior.

Comment: it is post request      Request URL: http://localhost:52832/Account/loginInfo
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:52832
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade